# Invalidated Oracle package on every subsequent call

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, odp.net

ODP.Net method calls a packaged stored procedure that re-create a table each time it is called.
on every subsequent call it throws error

```
ORA-04061: existing state of package body "SAAP.PRICEWORX" has been invalidated
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SAAP.PRICEWORX"
```

How can I circumevent this ?

Comment: From http://ora-04061.ora-code.com/, you just have to call it twice and it should work the second time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My immediate guess would be that your package also drops or references the table that you're creating. So, at some points the package may be trying to reference a non-existent table.

The sequence of events may go something like this:

1. Table exists
2. Use table
3. Drop table
4. Try to use table again - package is invalid as table no longer exists.
5. Create table - everything is fine again.

The simple answer is not to create or drop a table in code. Create a [global temporary table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables003.htm#ADMIN11633) instead. This enables the table to always be there.

The far worse option is to wrap every single call that uses that table that may, or may not, exist in an `execute immediate`.

If I'm completely wrong then you need to investigate why your package is invalid and post the results. The fact that it's invalid doesn't mean much.

Comment: Upvoted, thanks, for the informative answer. found shortcut solution by executing dbms_session.modify_package_state(dbms_session.reinitialize); at the begining of the proc.http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sessio.htm#BHCEIDAB

Comment: @TonyP, I'm glad to have helped and have to admit I have one `alter package compile` in my DB for the same reason; just not had time to fix the problem. If you can avoid doing this it is worth it though.

Answer (score 3):

Dropping any object causes all objects that reference it to be marked as invalid.  Objects that reference this invalidated object can also be marked as invalid, and so on.  So, it seems that either your package references this table, or depends on something that does.

I have to admit I understand the reason why Oracle throws an ORA-04061 error and doesn't automatically revalidate packages the first time you call an invalidated package.  However, I don't see this as a problem.  You shouldn't really be creating or dropping tables while an application is running.  Why do you need to do this?

If you're looking for a faster way of emptying the table than `DELETE FROM my_table`, then use `TRUNCATE TABLE my_table`.  Note that `TRUNCATE` is DDL, like `CREATE`, `ALTER` and `DROP`, so you will need to wrap the call to it in an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.